# Does Beijing still see natural sunrises?

Tags: china, sun, smog

In Januari 2014, [this article](http://www.techinasia.com/beijing-residents-watching-fake-sunrises-giant-tvs-pollution/) reported that:

> Over the weekend, a story that originated on the smut-ridden UK-based
>   Daily Mail went viral among major media outlets across the world.
>   Time, CBS, and the Huffington Post were among the dozens of online
>   news media who published stories about Beijing residents flocking to
>   giant TV screens to see fake sunrises during heavy pollution last
>   week. Most of these stories were accompanied by the same photo of a
>   massive TV screen in Tiananmen Square with a sunrise appearing on it.

[image: Heavily smogged/fogged Chinese square with giant widescreen display showing a red sunrise.]

The article goes on to say that Beijing residents are NOT watching fake sunrises on giant TVs because of pollution:

> In truth, that sunrise was probably on the screen for less than 10
>   seconds at a time, as it was part of an ad for tourism in China’s
>   Shandong province. The ad plays every day throughout the day all year
>   round no matter how bad the pollution is. The photographer simply
>   snapped the photo at the moment when the sunrise appeared.

That does not clearly answer the question of whether people can directly see a real sunrise in Beijing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is plenty of photographic evidence of sunrises over Beijing.

- Taken: 3 May, 2014, Taken by [Liu Hongan of Asianewsphoto](http://www.chinadaily.com.cn/regional/2014-05/05/content_17484907.htm):

> [image: Sunrise picture]

- Taken: 9 September, 2006, [Dan Desjardins](http://www.viewpix.com/beijing/)

> [image: Sunrise picture]

- Published: 8 July, 2013, [Burton Girls](http://burtongirls.burton.com/travel/foreign-correspondence-beijing-china/)

> [image: Sunrise picture]

- Taken: June 8, 2004, [Knexon Cho](https://www.flickr.com/photos/knexon/75913732/)

> [image: Sunrise picture]

Comment: Nice pictures. The best i found was [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KxpRQRHFcOc), which still looks a little [too smoky](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2013/12/12/china-smog-problem-space-photo_n_4433615.html).